# Как высчитать условия в одной ячейке Excel?

Tags: excel, if, условия

ЕСЛИ A1 МЕНЬШЕ 408, тогда нужно проверить на A2<40 %. Если второе верно также  выводить 1, если нет 0
ЕСЛИ A1 БОЛЬШЕ 408, тогда нужно проверить на A2<50 %. Если второе верно также  выводить 1, если нет 0
**Как это высчитывать в одной ячейке Excel?**

Comment: 40% относительно чего?

Comment: @Max можно и без процентов. Сверить условие A2<40 или как во втором случае A2<50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю вам подойдет эта функция:

```
=ЕСЛИ(И(A1<408; A2 < 40); 1; ЕСЛИ(И(A1>408; A2 < 50); 1; 0))
```

Comment: Отличное решение!

Answer (score 1):

```
=--ЕСЛИ(A1<408;A2<0,4;A2<0,5)
```

Здесь бинарное отрицание преобразует логическое значение в число.